# custom UiTableViewCell shrink while editin or deleting

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am using custom UitableViewcell (MainTablecell)to display the records. i am also providing edit and delete functionality.so that i want to shrink my custom table cell, can any one suggest me how to do this.
my custom cell looking like bellow
[image]

```
cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = YES;
```

and

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
return YES;
}
```

i tried with above poece of code but
**Both are not working for me,How can i shrink all lables in my cell could you please help for me**

Answer (score 1):

When your tableView goes into edit mode, resize the labels.

`shouldIndentWhileEditing:` only makes the left side of the cell indent and does nothing for the content. You will need to manually resize the labels.

Depending on the design and code of that custom cell, you can call the label and perform `setFrame:` when in editing mode, just detect that mode and reload your tableView.